# Connecting to AZURE DB from Local AD Group

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database

I'm having a challenge to connect to my Azure DB with local AD group member.

If I create my user like this `CREATE USER [bob@contoso.com] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;` 
and grant the user the db_owner 
I can log on the database - by using integrated security, and trusted connection directly to the DB (contained database)

but if I try to use the `CREATE USER [XY_DB_Owners] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;` where XY_DB_Owners is a AD-group in the company contoso.com.
the user creation works fine, and every thing looks like it is working. 
But SSMS gives this error when a member of the XY_DB_Owners group tries to log on.

```
Could not discover a user realm. (System.Data)
```

I have read and followed these articles - among a longer list of other pages: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure?tabs=azure-powershell#create-contained-database-users-in-your-database-mapped-to-azure-ad-identities
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-manage-logins
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5242/adding-users-to-azure-sql-databases/ and https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/148325/add-active-directory-user-for-azure-sql-db
still with no luck

Answer (score 0):

It was working as is. the reason for the problem - was that the user in the group was known to azure by the @contoso.onmicrosoft.com but the account had to beknown to azure by the @contoso.com